# Celery beat processed messages not removed from ready state

Tags: django, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue

I have Celery beat defined as:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/15')), name='threshold_monitor', ignore_result=True, queue='default', options={'queue': 'default'})
def threshold_monitor():
     #Threshold check login
```

Celery is run through supervisord as:

```
celery -A ProjectName beat --loglevel=info
```

The task is well executed every 15 minutes but it is not removed from the celery queue as expected. The number keeps growing in RabbitMq. Is this the expected behavior? If not, how do I fix it.

Other celery settings:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc'

CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True

CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True

CELERY_TASK_IGNORE_RESULT = True

CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1

CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'

CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 60
```

RabbitMQ queue screenshots: Note the default queue items are executed and released, but celery keeps growing.

[image]
[image]